# WebPageTest WPT Private Instance - Agents not deregistering with server

Tags: docker, containers, mesos, marathon, webpagetest

I have setup WPT (Web Page Test) private instance, using docker, mesos and marathon. 
However when I'm scaling up and down of agents, sometimes the server thinks that there are more agents connected (when looking at server-host/install/).

It looks like perhaps the agent doesn't "re-register" properly with the Server.

Questions:
- How does the agent notify the server that it is no longer connected?
- Is there an option I can pass when starting up the dockerized instance (of agent/server) or marathon config to notify the server when the instance is being scaled down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the marathon event bus. Basically you can subscribe to it. You can read more about it here:

https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/event-bus.html